# Disable caching of errors when using Apache as a proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, proxypass

When you use Apache proxying (using either ProxyPass or RewriteRule), if the destination returns an error (500 series status) then Apache won't proxy any more requests for 30 seconds.

I know there's a way to disable this by setting that value to 0 second, but I can't remember how. I think it involves a semicolon and some options but I can't seem to find that detail at apache.org.

In development environment, you'd want this value to be 0, so you can fix the error and reload the page immediately.

Answer (score 7):

You should use a setting like this; source [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

```
ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/ retry=0
```

Comment: Do you know how to accomplish the same thing when using mod_proxy through mod_rewrite with the [P] flag?